# Litecoin - how to calculate the difficulty from 2^-N

Tags: litecoin, difficulty

In the following list I always see difficulty values like 2^-12
How to calculate the actual difficulty from it?

[Comparison of mining pools](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/wiki/Comparison-of-mining-pools)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, actual difficulty is defined as the number `d` such that the probability of a random hash being valid is `1/(d*2^32)`. In other words, the hash needs to have at least `32 + log_2(d)` zeros in front of it to be valid. (This is not exactly the case if `d` is not a power of 2, but you get the general idea.)

In that article, a difficulty of `2^-12` means that the probability of a random share being valid is `1/(2^-12 * 2^32) = 2^-20`. Note that typically, pool difficulty, is measured in multiples of `2^-16` for reasons discussed in the article, so a difficulty of `2^-12` would be a pool difficulty of `2^4 = 16`.

Answer (score 0):

These figures represent the difficulty at which the respective mining pool accepts a hash as a *share* of the mining pool's work. **The actual network difficulty cannot be calculated from these figures.**

**Explanation:**
While Bitcoin uses `SHA256` as the hashing algorithm, Litecoin uses `Scrypt` which is much more complex.

Therefore, a Litecoin difficulty of 1 represented a much greater amount of work than a Bitcoin difficulty of 1. If Litecoin mining pool operators would have accepted only hashes that fulfilled a difficulty of 1 or greater as valid *shares*, they would have only accepted valid blocks as *shares*, essentially reducing their contributors to solo miners. In order to estimate the work done by their contributers, they allowed hashes that fulfilled a much lower difficulty as *shares*, as seen in the linked website.